# Are paypal recurring payments Prepaid or Postpaid?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I've been reading through all of the recurring payments documents and I can't find whether it is prepaid or postpaid.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

Is it just charged on the START of payment period? There is no post-paid options?

Answer (score 0):

The first payment will be made on the start date of the profile unless you include an initial amount.  So you could create a profile today, but set the start date to 1 month from now, for example.  That would create an "active" profile, but the first payment wouldn't be made until 30 days later (or whatever day you set as the start date of the profile.)